# How to restart ofelia container when depends_on container's labels are changed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` like this.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    labels:
      ofelia.enabled: "true"
      ofelia.job-exec.my-job.schedule: "0 0 11 * * *"
      ofelia.job-exec.my-job.command: "bundle exec ruby myjob"
  ofelia:
    image: mcuadros/ofelia:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: daemon --docker
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

I want to restart `ofelia` container when `web` container's schedule are changed.

But `docker-compose up -d --build` command rebuilds only `web` container and I need to restart `ofelia` container by `docker-compose restart ofelia` manually.

Is there a docker-compose option to restart a container when another container is rebuilt.